# Why a single character is replaced by either ╠

Tags: c, visual-studio

When i’m call `%с`, this symbol `╠` appears supply . When I `%s`, it's all right.

Windows 7 x64

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <stdio.h>
void main(void)
{
char a; 
scanf_s("%c",&a); 
printf("%c", a); 
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are using `scanf_s` wrong. You need to include the buffer size.

Comment: ah yes, the "safe" version of scanf folks

Answer (score 1):

`scanf_s()`function, in case of `%c` conversion specifier, expects two arguments (the usual pointer and a value indicating the size of the receiving array, which may be 1 when reading with a `%c` into a single `char`). Try the following `scanf_s("%c",&a, 1)` or use `scanf("%c",&a)`. See details and examples via the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2019).